# DrawableRight to right end of EditText or Button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable

I want my `drawableRight` at the end of my edit text.

[image]

As you can see in the picture it is not at the end.

Code of my EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/btnDB"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textfield2r"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/db_ic"
    android:ems="10"
    android:text="Daten einsehen"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textColorHint="#7A7A7A"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
```

And here the xml of the background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#EBEBEB"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#D30F1D"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

At the end it should look like this: [image]

Thanks for helping me,
kind regards, Jeremy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to fix it.

I made a RTL linear layout in which i put in my EditText:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/btnData"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="52dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:background="@drawable/textfield2r"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/console"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:text="Daten einsehen"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textColorHint="#7A7A7A"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Then I changed the xml of my button background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#EBEBEB"/>
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#D30F1D"/>
<padding
    android:bottom="-1dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="-8dp"
    android:top="0dp"/>
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>
```

Now everything is like i wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the end padding to `0dp` instead of `5dp`

Or ideally you can set it to `1dp` as the stroke of the background is `1dp`

Also set the `paddingTop` to 1dp to make the stroke frame appear at the bottom

```
<EditText
    .....
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:paddingEnd="1dp"
    android:paddingRight="1dp"
```

Test:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that is not what i wantet to have. I edited my post so you can understand what i am planning to do.

Comment: @JeremyBrehe sorry to know.. So, now the change is to have 0 padding and align the text to the right I guess?

Comment: Even 0dp padding does not work. There is always some space between the right corner...

Comment: @JeremyBrehe even setting `android:layout_margin="0dp"` doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: @JeremyBrehe I couldn't reproduce your issue.. please consider [creating a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so somebody can help you